# Can we mount a Vue component to multiple div element?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

```
import Selector from '@components/contactSelector'
let vueInstance = new Vue({
  components: { Selector },
  data () {
    return {
      url: url,
      isFilter: false,
      type: 'external',
      selectedList: []
    }
  },
  render (h) {
    return h(Selector, { props: { url, selectedList: this.selectedList, maxHeight: '300px' } })
  }
})
```

I have an above Vue instance created, can we call to render it on multiple divs. I have tried but this seems not working is there any way to mount on multiple divs or it is meant to be like this only single div it will be mounted. If anyone knows please help here. Thanks.

```
vueInstance.$mount('#contactSelectorId')
vueInstance.$mount('#contactSelectorId2')
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Looks like what you need is that this component will be a child component of another one.

Comment: I have exported the vue js code to plain es module wanted the component to be used in a page at multiple places here, which is not a vue js code where I will be using this component.

Comment: From the es module, I will be returning the single Vue instance created to the caller, I was looking if they can call the mount on the multiple div to render as there are no changes in the behaviour creating another instance is also a solution but was hoping if there is any way we can mount on multiple div. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you are trying to do can be achieved by having a root component which can include your component as a child component.

If you need that one component will appear several times in the same page, this is the direction:

Base component:

```
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

export default {
    components: {
        ChildComponent
    },

    :
    :
```

Then you can simply include it (`<child-component/>`) in any place you need.

Notice, that in this case the new parent component is the one you need to assign to your `vueInstance` in order to become the root.

Comment: From the es module, I will be returning the single Vue instance created to the caller, I was looking if they can call the mount on the multiple div to render as there are no changes in the behaviour creating another instance is also a solution but was hoping if there is any way we can mount on multiple div. Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand why don't you want to create a parent component that will hold instants of your component. Instead of mixing html with vue, keep everything under the same umbrella.